# Angular 9 ReactiveFormsModule - email validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I have currently facing an issue of getting the email valdiated properly:
If I set "Validators.email" then: me@host is validated to true, which is not suitable in my case.

**me@host should not validate,

me@host.domain should validate.**

I have tried the following two methods, none of them are helping. Only required is being validated properly but not the email validation.

```
Email: new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+$')
])

Email: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+$')
]))
```

[**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmfzxv)

solutions please...

Comment: Could you also share your template / hmtl.?

Comment: @LaminooLawrance I have provided the stackblitz link. you can see.. test@test is being validated as a valid email address, i dont want that.. it should be test@host.domain not the other.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using like below to validate an email

```
/**
   * Actual validator function
   * @param ctrl FormControl that contains the input validation state
   */
  return function emailValidator(ctrl: FormControl) {
    if (ctrl && ctrl.value) {
      const value: string = ctrl.value;
      // tslint:disable-next-line
      const regEx = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
      // tslint:disable-next-line
      const isValidEmail = regEx.test(value)

      // signify to the Angular form control whether the value is valid
      return isValidEmail ? null : { email: true };
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: do u have a stackblitz example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the backslash to the dot in your regex. Use `\\.` instead of `\.`

```
Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]+$')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not setting `type=email` in your input element in your HTML

```
<input  type="email"
      name="Email"
      [formControl]="form.controls['Email']"
    />
```

Also, you need not use a pattern to validate an email, you can simply set the email as one of the validators  as below,

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  Email: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])]
});
```

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-l4v2nw)**

Comment: I have provided the stackblitz link. you can see.. test@test is being validated as a valid email address, i dont want that.. it should be test@host.domain not the other.